# Plotting axvspan based on the value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the background of a plot to highlight intervals where a certain pandas column is >0 and <3.

I first checked `axvspan`, but find no easy way of passing the column and automatically getting the intervals.

Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233552/how-do-i-use-axvfill-with-a-boolean-series) and tried to make it work with :

```
ax.fill_between(df.index, ax.get_ylim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[1], where=df.mycol<3, alpha=0.4)
```

Nevertheless, I am getting a MemoryError from matplotlib (which I don't get for the plot without the fill_between function), so it seems the method is not appropriated for a big dataframe with too many internvals (maybe?).

Any alternative?