# Matplotlib conditional statement filling

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, fill

I have a 0/1 variable with 0=no recession and 1=recession and I want to shade periods with recessions. I do NOT want to plot a histogram using dual y axis. My goals is to use some other method (axvspan, fill etc).

I found this answer which almost works for me ([How do I use axvfill with a boolean series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233552/how-do-i-use-axvfill-with-a-boolean-series)), but it forces the graph to display the entire X range even when I want to zoom in.

Is it possible to fix the above solution so that it would allow me to zoom in? Or should another solution be used? Thank you.

This is my current charting code:

```
fig, ax1=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.fill_between(df.index, 0,1,where=df['RECESSION'], alpha=0.4,transform=ax2.get_xaxis_transform())
ax1.plot(df['REL']['2022-09-01':'2022-12-01'],'b',linewidth=1)
ax2.plot(df['US10']['2022-09-01':'2022-12-01'],'r--',linewidth=1)
```

and here is the data:

```
            US10    REL         RECESSION
Dates           
2022-06-05  2.92    0.826972    0.0
2022-06-12  3.04    0.821700    1.0
2022-06-19  3.28    0.831073    1.0
2022-06-26  3.09    0.822982    1.0
2022-07-03  2.98    0.823109    0.0
2022-07-10  3.01    0.812530    0.0
2022-07-17  2.96    0.806165    0.0
2022-07-24  2.91    0.807227    0.0
2022-07-31  2.68    0.806655    0.0
2022-08-07  2.68    0.803642    0.0
2022-08-14  2.87    0.817092    0.0
2022-08-21  2.88    0.814631    0.0
2022-08-28  3.03    0.810260    0.0
2022-09-04  3.26    0.820891    0.0
2022-09-11  3.29    0.828855    0.0
2022-09-18  3.45    0.838984    0.0
2022-09-25  3.70    0.839056    0.0
2022-10-02  3.76    0.829300    0.0
2022-10-09  3.83    0.828128    0.0
2022-10-16  3.97    0.835641    0.0
2022-10-23  4.24    0.841246    0.0
2022-10-30  3.96    0.845483    0.0
2022-11-06  4.14    0.855199    1.0
2022-11-13  3.82    0.853006    1.0
2022-11-20  3.77    0.848167    1.0
2022-11-27  3.71    0.852128    1.0
2022-12-04  3.53    0.846362    1.0
2022-12-11  3.48    0.843546    1.0
2022-12-18  3.44    0.844612    1.0
2022-12-25  3.67    0.859020    1.0
2023-01-01  3.83    0.862859    1.0
2023-01-08  3.71    0.872137    1.0
2023-01-15  3.43    0.863680    1.0
2023-01-22  NaN     NaN         1.0
2023-01-29  NaN     NaN         1.0
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: complete dataset can be found here, its too long to copy passte into the question; we.tl/t-7TFtOizB6v

Comment: I have downvoted the question - [please do not post the images of the code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please add the image of the output figure directly in the question. To save the figure generated using matplotlib, please see [`plt.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).

Comment: the question has all the code from the image written at the bottom

Comment: @user20856754 Please actually read the page I linked. Specific data is definitely not needed for a question reading a specific plot. You can use 5-10 dummy values that you specify and create a *complete* and *minimal* code example that anyone can copy&paste in one step to see what happens.

Comment: @user20856754 Yes, I understand. But is it not then redundant to have the code again in the image? As the linked meta Q&A suggests, it is strongly advised not to post the image of the code. I'll remove the downvote once the post is improved on these aspects.

Comment: added values so the question can be replicated + removed the image

Comment: Please see if this helps: [Plotting the data with scrollable x (time/horizontal) axis on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31001713/7789963)